# Issue with the alarm manager class. I'm setting the alarm but it is not triggered on that time

Tags: android

I'm working on an app that will put phone on silent on a specific time and on ringer mode on a specific time. But when I set the time for the silent it is triggered in the next minute and ringer mode is triggered just after that silent mode trigger. Here is the code.

```
     long sdl = calendar.getTimeInMillis();// here calendar has the time on which it should trigger
    mgrAlarm[number]= (AlarmManager) this.getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), AlarmReceiver.class);
    intent.putExtra("Id",id);
    final int _id = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();
    PendingIntent appIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(), id,intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
    mgrAlarm[number].set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, sdl, appIntent);
```

Comment: what is the android os version r u testing ?

Comment: btw you aren't using the `_id` variable anywhere

Comment: I;m using Lollipop 5.0.1

Comment: You should use `setExact()` >= KITKAT, and you should use `setExactAndAllowWhileIdle()` >= MARSHMALLOW

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes! Use `setExact(int, long, PendingIntent)`Method Instead `set` method.

please attention to android developer documentation:

> Note: Beginning with API 19 (KITKAT) alarm delivery is inexact: the OS
>   will shift alarms in order to minimize wakeups and battery use. There
>   are new APIs to support applications which need strict delivery
>   guarantees; see setWindow(int, long, long, PendingIntent) and
>   setExact(int, long, PendingIntent). Applications whose
>   targetSdkVersion is earlier than API 19 will continue to see the
>   previous behavior in which all alarms are delivered exactly when
>   requested.

See  following link for more information: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html

Please Vote and mark this answer if it work!

Comment: Likely problem is  in your calendar time. Are you set exact it? for example if you set alarm to 2 pm you should set it to 14:00:00.